# Foreach Json check if the value is greater then 0

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

How do i get foreach Json result check if one off the objects (Stage2) is greater then 0 then amendTo a div.

```
 function service(){   
var service_id=document.getElementById('down').value;
     $.ajax({
             'type': "POST",
        'data' : "postData",
        'url': "clients.php",
        'data':"service_id="+service_id+"&sid="+Math.random(),
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
                var json = data;
                        $("#checkboxes").empty();
                            $("#check").empty();
             var $grouplist = $('#checkboxes');
             var $list = $('#check');    
$.each(json,function() 
{
     $('#createEventModal #stage1').val(this.Stage1);
      $('#createEventModal #gap1').val(this.Gap1);
       $('#createEventModal #Stage1Desc1').val(this.Stage1Desc1);
     $('#createEventModal #stage2').val(this.Stage2);
     $('#createEventModal #gap2').val(this.Gap2);
           $('#createEventModal #Stage2Desc2').val(this.Stage2Desc2);
        //    $('#createEventModal #GapTime3').val(this.GapTime3);
     $('#createEventModal #Stage3').val(this.Stage3);
      $('#createEventModal #Stage3Desc3').val(this.Stage3Desc3);
     $('#createEventModal #cost').val(this.cost);
     if (typeof Stage2 > 0){
      $('<div class="pull-left"><span><b>'+this.service+' - '+this.desc+ ' '+this.cost+'</b></span> </div>').appendTo($grouplist);}

});
```

So if Stage2 return more then 0 show div I have tried several things including typeof but with no success

Comment: @Andi AR the post returns `[{"id":"1","service":"Perm Full Head","desc":"Full Head Perm test","cost":"65.00","Stage1":"40","Gap1":"30","Stage2":"20","Gap2":"0","Stage1Desc1":"tesst1","Stage2Desc2":"adaas","Gap3":null,"Stage3":"20","Stage3Desc3":"ffsdsf"}]` I need to check if stage2 and stage 3 are empty then appenTo. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that should be `if (typeof this.Stage2 > 0){ ...` but hat doesn't make any sense.

You want to check whether stage2 is defined and has a value greater than zero:

`if (typeof this.Stage2 != 'undefined' && this.stage2 > 0 ) { ...`

**According to comment:**

`if (typeof this.Stage2 != 'undefined' && parseInt(this.stage2) > 0 ) { ...`

to ensure you're comparing Ints and not a string containing a number with an Int

Comment: I have tried `if (typeof this.Stage2 != 'undefined' && this.stage2 > 0 ) { ` before but I div does not get amendTo should I be trying a different approach! . Stage always returns a number or 0

Comment: Yes it was parseInt I was missing Thank you!

Comment: Please check your typing, this is hardly to understand: "appendTo" and not amendTo. Are you using a tablet? Turn off spell checking ;-)

Answer (score 1):

simply it should be if(this.Stage2 > 0)
and you can add if(parseInt(this.Stage2) > 0 ) to be sure that this.Stage2 is an integer so it can be comparable .